# How to calculate total time for each loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, each, jquery

Consider a repeating loop of

```
setInterval(function(){
$('.test').each(function(idx){
    var duration = 1000;
    $(this).delay(duration*idx);
    Some stuff here
});
}, 4000);
```

How can I calculate the total time spent for the internal loop to set the `setInterval` dynamically?

Here, if we have 4 elements with class of `test`, the cycle works perfectly with `setInterval` of `4000`. How can I make a variable to set this value dynamically? For example, setting it `6000`, when we have 6 elements, and so forth.

My problem is that, I cannot use the value of `duration*idx` for `setInterval`, as it is inside the `idx function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to count the number of elements:

```
var total  = $('.test').length,
    timer  = 1000,
    result = parseInt(timer*total);
```

And then, perform your actions!

---

**EDITED, to clarify the use of .lenght over .size():**

*The [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method is functionally equivalent to the [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property; however, the [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.*

Comment: @VisioN [`size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) just returns length. You can save yourself from an additional function call with `length`.

Comment: There! Updated answer! Thanks for the enlightenment :)

Comment: @Joseph If you look at the internal iterations calling a method is 2 iterations more than addressing a property.

Comment: @VisioN which worse than one. justifies the use of `length` even more :)

Answer (score 3):

Simplest method is to have diff. between start and elapased time.

```
start = new Date().getTime();
 elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
```